# Rich calendar automatic "/" sign in input

Tags: date, primefaces, calendar, richfaces

How can I put "/" sign in calendar field by hand input?

Users can be enter date by hand not selecting date popup window. So, I must put automatic "/" sign in field.

For example;
**11/12/2014**

If user enters **11**, field should be **11/** automatic.

Then when user enters **12**, field should be **11/12/**.

Finally user enters **2014** and field should be **11/12/2014**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mask on an input field, you have the example in the showcases http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml, try the example with the mask label and note the

```
<p:outputLabel for="mask" value="Mask:" />
<p:calendar id="mask" value="#{calendarView.date9}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" mask="true" />
```

insded the *xhtml*. Your' mask would of course be

```
    <p:outputLabel for="mask" value="Mask:" />
    <p:calendar id="mask" value="#{calendarView.date9}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mask="true" />
```

not 100% what you need, but this is as far as you'll get using primefaces only.